# Keycloak role policies are not persisted correctly

Tags: keycloak

Keycloak does not seem to save any modifications I make to role policies.

When I configure my role policy inside keycloak and I click save, there is indeed a row added in the POLICY_CONFIG table inside my database. However when I reload the policy page inside the keycloak admin interface, the policy is empty again. I am not seeing any error inside the logs.

## Steps to reproduce

### Configure policy

[image: Configure policy]

### Save policy (successful)

[image: Save successfull]

### Reload policy page

All fields are empty again. I waited a minute but nothing is being loaded.

[image: Reload policy page]

### Oracle database

#### POLICY_CONFIG table

ID:

```
13b25a3a-95f9-4fb7-bbed-bb758c887c8d
```

TYPE: roles

VALUE

```
[{"id":"fac49c05-2e78-40a3-98cc-e6206188ed8c","required":false},{"id":"a141db57-
51b5-469d-9266-4bd14fcd024e","required":false},{"id":"679dbf0e-47da-449a-832a-28
0c766381f4","required":false},{"id":"c4993ff8-32fa-4731-9b50-2b75084d1974","requ
ired":false},{"id":"cdc2ac65-7bde-4883-a2b7-7a4af56770e1","required":false}]
```

Comment: Can you show what is happening?

Comment: Yes sorry, stackoverflow didn't want to submit my screenshots. I removed them and will try to add them again.

Comment: @RobAnthony I added some screenshots and the database values